# Create two dimensional array with values dynamically in Java

Tags: java, arrays

My array currently looks like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

And I am trying to make it look like this:

```
0  10 25 15 30 
10 0  20 0  0
25 20 0  0  0
15 0  0  0  0
30 0  0  0  0
```

using the following code I create the first but don't know how I can get the result I want.

```
int rows = array.length;
int columns = array[0].length;

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?.

Comment: What's the pattern?

Comment: Where do these numbers come from?  Tell us what the pattern is, and somebody might be able to help.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I created the array `int[][] matrix = new int[5][5];` which is 5x5 as you see above, and then looped through it's rows and columns and printed like you see in the last piece of code. That leaves me with all those zeroes in the beggining. I am simply asking if there is a way to increase those zeroes within the loop in order to get the pattern in the second piece of code.

Comment: You can assign any value in the array to anything you like.  It's really not clear what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the second matrix you show on the post then you must assign those values to the corresponding cells of the matrix you have created before printing the matrix, because doing

```
int matrix[][] = new int[n][n];
```

will create a matrix of dimension NxN but filled in every cell with a 0

I don't know the logic to fill your matrix (reading from user input or generated by some algorithm) but for every row and column that you want to fill with a value different from 0 you need to do an assignment:

```
matrix[row][col] = someInt;
```